# how can I make pi chart through extracted table data?

Tags: r

I extracted two tables, parent and child table. I wanted to express this data through pi chart. the more the parent data has more child data, the more its proportion of the pi getting bigger.

the parent table : `CLASS` 
the child table : `REF_CLASS`

related column `CLASS_ID`

how can I achieve this?

---

**UPDATE**

Parent table

```
           PJT_ID APPLICATION CLASS_ID CLASS_TYPE
1 PJT201510067777    legalApp    26241          *
2 PJT201510067777    legalApp    26243          *
3 PJT201510067777    legalApp    26245          *
4 PJT201510067777    legalApp    26247          *
5 PJT201510067777    legalApp    26249          *
6 PJT201510067777    legalApp    26251          *
```

Child table

```
           PJT_ID APPLICATION CLASS_ID REF_CLASS_ID
1 PJT201510067777    legalApp    25951        26697
2 PJT201510067777    legalApp    25247        26791
3 PJT201510067777    legalApp      805          361
4 PJT201510067777    legalApp    25673        26697
5 PJT201510067777    legalApp    25951        26693
6 PJT201510067777    legalApp      576        25195
```

Comment: I think you have to show some data example. But if i understand , see `group by` and `summarize` in `dplyr`

Comment: @dplyr As you request, I updated and showed my data. give some elaborate explanation. thanks in adavance :)

Comment: @Nikos thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
library( dplyr)
a=group_by(REF_CLASS,CLASS_ID)
a=summarize(a,count_n=n())
CLASS=merge(CLASS,a,by="CLASS_ID", all.x=T)
gr_class=group_by(CLASS,PJT_ID)
gr_class=summarize(gr_class,d=sum(count_n,na.rm=T)
```

and then i think you can plot pie